# How can I print the whole content of this out on a page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, printing

I really can't find a way to print the content of the array on a page. Can anyone help?
I have taken the data from a database and looped it into an javascript array and now would like to just display it on the page for now.

Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>

<script>


var items = {


<?php

   $con = mysql_connect("***","****","*****");
   if (!$con)
   {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("learning_game", $con);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");


  $first=true;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if (!$first){
echo ",";
}
  $first = false;
echo "{name='" . $row['word'] . "',image='" . $row['image'] ."'}";

 }


 mysql_close($con);


   ?>



   };

   </script>

   </head>

<body>




</body>

   </html>
```

Comment: A `for` loop should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for all the fast replies. Can anyone help me with example code so I can work out how to print it on a page? I know nothing about javascript so any help would be great. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <script>
      var items = [
      <?php
      $con = mysql_connect("***","****","*****");
      if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      mysql_select_db("learning_game", $con);
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
      $first = true;
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if (!$first) {
          echo ",";
        }
        $first = false;
        echo "{name:'" . $row['word'] . "',image:'" . $row['image'] ."'}";
      }
      mysql_close($con);
      ?>
      ];
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML += items[i].name + ":" + items[i].image + "<br />\n";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please note, that the `items` declaration is now with `[` `]` signs, so it becomes an array, not an object.

In the line where you echo out the name and image the equals signs became colons (:).

As well as the full script had to be moved to the bottom, because you can only write into elements which are already rendered (closed). So I have added a new `div` into the mix, and write into that.